# Testing NFC or Beam using one device?

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I'm playing around with Beam and NFC but I only own one android device, is it possible to simulate or test the transmission with just one physical device?

Comment: No. Not unless you have hardware support, AFAIK.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314569/how-to-test-nfc-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can theoretically do this by building an intent that a scanned tag would create and starting an activity with that intent. You would basically encapsulate the payload inside of an extra in the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent and try to start an activity with the intent. Check out this sample tag canon app.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Tag/com/android/apps/tagcanon/TagCanon.java.htm

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you would need at least some NFC tags for testing NFC.

A second possiblity would be a NFC transponder (maybe cheaper than a second phone), but I do not have any experience on this til now.